# Finding hidden images in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to change image name , and i get :

```
The file could not be renamed because a file with that name already exists
```

I CANT find that image in there,(project assets)  it was deleted.

How can i be sure that its not in there ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you delete it from disk or just remove the reference? Check the project folder on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode shows what's in the project, not what's in the project's folder.

Open the folder of the file you want to rename (right click on the file in Xcode -> Show in Finder), and you'll probably see another file with the name you were trying to rename to. Remove that other file (if you're sure you don't need it).

Comment: yes, i know that, this is my second year with xcode. the thing is, that in the project folder, there isnt any file like that, he was deleted. he is probably hidden and my question is how to find it. i have cleaned the project also. nothing.

Comment: Unless you hid the file yourself, there's no reason it should be hidden in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do move forward is get out of the IDE:

1. Remove the file from Xcode, but not the filesystem, by "Deleting" the file and selecting "Delete Reference Only"
2. Rename the file in the filesystem(finder or terminal)
3. Re-add it to the project file.

Caveat: Confirm you aren't renaming the file with the same name, but with only a case change, that gets a little weird, mostly with SCM tools, but also OSX filesystems are case-insensitve by default, so File.m and file.m are the same file.